# Screen size columns on bootstrap not seems to be applying correctly

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-grid

I'm creating a page with Bootstrap 4 + Asp.Net MVC. I want to create a 4 column layout on large screens, and 2 columns on medium devices. So I created this:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

the bootstrap 4 documentation says that col-lg-* will be applied to devices larger then 1200px, while col-md-* applies to devices larger than 992px:
[image]

But when I run the site, using Chrome to simulate various resolutions, 
in 1024px i still have 4 columns, only when setting 991px i get 2 columns.

Using Chrome developer tools, i saw this: 
[image]

It says that col-lg- is set to a min width of 992px, shouldn't it be 1200px, as the documentation says? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help you out. Use `class row` not `form-row` and if it's `bootstrap` 4+ then you can use `xl` `class` too

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```